# iOS swift - data not showing up in table view in custom view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to display some simple data in the table view, but I see only table rows without data.  Here is class.

```
class DoctorInfoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var outerTableView: UITableView!


var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print("DoctorInfoViewController is called.")
    self.outerTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.outerTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

}

My storyboard has a tab-based view. There are 5 tabs at the bottom. View associated with each tab is custom view controller. One of them is 'Doctor Info' which is associated with this DoctorInfoViewController. When I launch this, I see only table rows, but no data.[image]

I added the image.  Am I doing something wrong or is there any attribute that I need to check?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to call `reloadData()` on the table view at some point? Btw: If you are using prototypes cells don't register the cell. And if there is only one table view in the scene **never** use the outlet in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, use the passed `tableView` instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Where should I call reloadData()?

Comment: In this case at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I commend out the register code and replaced it with self.outerTableView.reloadData(). but it behaves same. I guess it's related to the refresh table view.

Comment: Is this supposed to be Swift 3? If yes the signatures of the data source delegate methods are wrong.

Comment: Yes. it's swift 3. I copied it from somewhere to learn iOS with Swift.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144156/discussion-between-user826323-and-vadian).

Comment: I was offline for a few hours. If you really want to learn Swift – I doubt you can learn anything by c&p code – here are two suggestions to help yourself: #1: ⌘-click on `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` and look up the proper signatures in the header files. #2: Comment out the entire code of `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, type `table` and select the appropriate method(s) in the suggested completions.